# .htaccess rewrite url parameters and keys

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm at odd on how to use .htaccess to rewrite urls.
Can anyone shed some light on the following rewrite please?

original: `index.php?param1=value1`
desired: `index.php/param1/value1`

and
original: `index.php?param2=value2`
desired: `index.php/param2/value2`

param1 and param2 are fixed but their values are different.

On index.php then I'd like to retrieve the parameters with $_[GET]

I'm trying something like this

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} conf=(.+)`

`RewriteRule ^ /%1/? [R,L](.+)`

for the param1 = conf.

Comment: Do you already have the rewrite in place?

Comment: Please do not post the code in comment section. Edit your question to include it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rewrite rule would look something like

`RewriteRule ^index.php/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+) /index.php?$1=$2 [L]`

Comment: What if I'd like to get rid of index.php and simply have mydomain.com/param1/value1?

Comment: Remove the `index.php/`part, becomes `RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)/([^\/]+) /index.php?$1=$2 [L]`

Comment: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ is a great tool to help you test your rewrites.